# Найти количество делителей факториала

Tags: python

Делители факториала

По заданному натуральному числу N необходимо вычислить количество натуральных чисел, которые являются делителями N! (факториала числа N).

Например, при N=4, N!=4⋅3⋅2⋅1=24. Это число имеет следующие делители: 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24. Таким образом, искомое количество составляет 8.

Напишите программу, которая по натуральному N находит количество делителей его факториала.

Написал данный код, но он не работает, чт не так?

```
import math
n = int(input())
n = math.factorial(n)
div = []
for divisors in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % divisors == 0:
    div.append(divisors)
print(len(div))
```

Comment: в чем выражается "не работает"? работает же

Comment: вообще для факториала есть специальная функция в math, но даже без нее для чего складывать все числа в список ``а``, кода можно просто ``a`` в цикле умножать на ``i`` и там сразу получится факториал. И не понадобится забивать гвозди микроскопом, используя нампи.

Comment: есть что то не работает. напишите что именно не работает) пожалуйста)

Comment: если что то не работает, проверьте что факториал правильно расчитался, больше вариантов нет, остальное все вернно

Comment: я исправил программу и теперь она выполняется слич=шком долго, посмотрите вверху пожалуйста

Comment: то есть программа работает, но куда я забиваю для проверки не принимает

Comment: задача решается вычислением одной единственной формулы, без всяких переборов (который у вас можно сократить в два раза). И если внимательно посмотреть на список делителей или подумать, какие числа могут быть делителями N!, то можно сообразить как очень быстро вычислить их количество.

Comment: сделал. спасиюо